# Accepting only numbers in the user input c++

Tags: c++

Right now I am using this function to get the user input.

```
int getOnlyNumber(int num)
{
    while (!(cin >> num)) {
        // Reset the input:
        cin.clear();
        // Get rid of the bad input before return was pressed:
        while (cin.get() != '\n')
        {
            continue;
        }
        // Ask user to try again:
        cout << "Please enter a number:  ";
    }
    return num;
}
```

This seems to only catch bad input if the letter is entered first.  If a number is entered first, the program accepts it.  Ex. it will accept 1e but will catch e1.
This is being used like this:

```
displayChoice = getOnlyNumber(displayChoice);
```

Where displayChoice is an int.
What do i need to change to catch 1e as a input or any other input that starts with a number but has strings?

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: What do i add to catch things like 1e as a input. Right now it's not catching it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give it a partial number then, by default, it does the best it can and gives you the bits it did manage to understand.

If you want to see if there was an error during the conversion then you have to check cin.fail().

```
    while (!(cin >> num) || cin.get()!='\n') {
    ...
```

Comment: It still does not catch input that start with numbers and has letters like 4ffsd or 2ddd22.

Comment: Looked further into this (I never use the standard streams myself) and it's not an error because the stream stops processing when it reaches an invalid character. You can tell an error has occurred if calling cin.get() returns anything other than '\n'. Amended accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::all_of` to test if an entire string is a number:

```
std::string str;
auto is_digit_check = [] (unsigned char c) { return std::isdigit(c); };
while (!(std::cin >> str) ||
       !std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), is_digit_check))
{
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}

return std::stoi(str);
```

Comment: So I have to take in the input as a string and convert that into an int in the input is good?  Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: @Hulu You could also use [regular expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) to search for the correct pattern, but yes, this is the best way to do it for this simple example. For more complex patterns regex's seem to be the best solution.